# Как передать с формы 2 переменных которые находятся в select option?

Tags: php, javascript

С формы передается выбранное значение селекта переменная **$val['myid']**, мне нужно передать с формы еще переменную **$matn** но эта переменная должна передаваться вместе с  выбранным option.

```html
<form method="POST"  name="apple" id="apple" action="tabl.php" target="_blank">
  <select class="selectpicker" name="user" id="user" data="<?=$matn?>" >
    <option disabled selected >Выбрать сотрудника</option>
      <? foreach($row as $k=>$val){ 
        $matn=$val['mname'];
        $matn=substr($matn,0,-6);
      ?>
       <option value="<?=$val['myid']?>" id="link" > <?=$val['mname']?> </option>
      <?     
        }
      ?>
  </select>    
</form>
```

Comment: Сделайте ее в скрытый инпут, и при посте формы будет передан и он.

Comment: селект содержит 30 значений, переменная инпут тоже 30 значений, если добавляю скрытое поле то передается последний элемент.А мне нужно чтобы передавалось значение выбранное от селекта

Comment: Для каждого селекта свое значение $matn? Или для каждой опции? Если второе то,например, соедините их в одну переменную с разделителем - например $val['myid']___$math и такое высылайте на сервер, там себе разделяйте. Это все варианты без javascript

Comment: И да, что за переменная инпут о которой говорите? Добавляйте в вопрос всю информацию которая может помочь в помощи вам

Comment: да, для каждого opton свое значение как и для переменной $matn

Comment: Если у вас `matn` - это кусок `mname`, до достаточно по переданному `myid` получить `mname` и выковырять из него `matn`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вариант "составной ключ" без js.

```
    <form method="POST"  name="apple" id="apple" action="tabl.php" target="_blank">
  <select class="selectpicker" name="user" id="user" data="<?=$matn?>" >
    <option disabled selected >Выбрать сотрудника</option>
      <? foreach($row as $k=>$val){ 
        $matn=$val['mname'];
        $matn=substr($matn,0,-6);
      ?>
       <option value="<?=echo $val['myid'] . "/". $matn ?>" id="link" > <?=$val['mname']?> </option>
      <?                
        }
      ?>
  </select>    
</form>
```

На сервере делаем:

```
$user = explode("/", $_POST['user']);
```

Первый элемент - id, второй - name

Вариант с js :

```
<form method="POST"  name="apple" id="apple" action="tabl.php" target="_blank">
 <input type="hidden" name="user_name" value="1">
  <select class="selectpicker" name="user" id="user" data="<?=$matn?>" >
    <option disabled selected >Выбрать сотрудника</option>
      <? foreach($row as $k=>$val){ ?>
       <option value="<?=$val['myid']?>" id="link" > <?=$val['mname']?> </option>
      <?                
        }
      ?>
  </select>    
</form>
```

```js
function setName(elem) {
  var text = elem.options[elem.selectedIndex].text;
  text = text.substr(0, text.length - 6);
   document.getElementById('user_name').value = text;
}
```

```html
<input id="user_name" name="user_name" type="hidden" />
<select name="user" onchange="setName(this)">
 <option value="1">Алексей123456</option>
 <option value="2">Василий123456</option>
</select>
```

Ну и на беке уже достать из поста `$_POST['user_name']  $_POST['user']`

Comment: Полностью решили мой вопрос, спасибо вам. Один вопрос остался, в первом варианте я получаю переменную $user как массив а как сделать переменную ? Дело в том что эту переменную $user я поставлю в код и ищу файл на сервере с похожим именем. пример кода `echo "<pre>";
  if(file_exists($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']."/project/$user.sql")){
   $sql = file_get_contents($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']."/project/$user.sql");
  }
 else echo "Нет данного файла";
 echo $sql;
 echo "</pre>";`

Comment: можно сделать так `$userArr = explode("/", $_POST['user']);$user = $userArr[0]; $userName = $userArr[1];` И потом работать дальше c $user и $userName